# resize problem in scroll area

Tags: c++, qt

Hello everyone, here is my code:

```
myplot *p = new myplot(gao.structpayloadgraph, 
                       gao1.structpayloadgraph, 
                       gao.structcol-2, "payload");

ui->scrollArea->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
ui->scrollArea->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
ui->scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(false);
p->resize(ui->scrollArea->size().width(), ui->scrollArea->size().height());

ui->scrollArea->setWidget(p);
```

I want `p` to take up the full available space of the scrollbar area and fit itself. However, the appearance looks 'squeezed' even though I called the resize function. What should I do to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Why have you written `ui->scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(false);`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to treat the scroll area content widget as a normal `QWidget`. If you want automatic resize and you must use layouts in Qt. Try the following :

```
QVBoxLayout layout = new QVBoxLayout( ui->scrollAreaContent);
layout->setMargin(0);
layout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
layout->setSpacing(0);
ui->scrollAreaContent->setLayout( layout);
layout->addWidget(p);
```

NOTE: `ui->scrollAreaContent` is a guess, but I think you are using `ui` files and default content widget is named like that ...

Answer (score 0):

Go to the top right of the QT creator designer screen (Object, Class), right click on the QScrollArea row and select the "Lay Out" menu item, choose a layout (eg vertical or horizontal layout), make sure that your QWidget has a minimum or above size policy. Your scroll widget should now resize with the layout.